# Override <excludes> configuration for maven-jar-plugin inside a profile

Tags: maven

I have the following root config for the maven-jar-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <excludes>
           <exclude>com/company/project/staging/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to override this config in maven profile with this configuration:

```
<profile>
  <id>staging</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/**</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

However the profile config does not override the root config so the package com/company/project/staging/ is still excluded. With help of the

> mvn help:all-profiles

command I can clearly see that my profile is active. Any idea why it does not work as I expect it to work? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

When your profile is active, both the includes and excludes elements are used in the merged configuration.  To fix that, you could add an empty `<excludes>` element in the configuration definition in your profile, which will override the defined excludes in your main configuration if the `combine.self="override"` modifier is used.

It looks like that all you want to do is eliminate the exclude in your profile, so you can probably omit the `<include>` element as well.

`<profile>
  <id>staging</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes combine.self="override" />
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it is a union - not an override, so <exludes/> inside profile does not help.

Comment: Indeed you are right - updated answer to add `combine.self="override"` - not tested myself but it might do the job.

Comment: @prunge Can confirm that combine.self="override" works

Comment: This approach also works with the `excludesFile` option. To override an exclusion defined in the default profile, simply add an empty `excludesFile` entry in your specific profile:
`<excludesFile combine.self="override" />`

Answer (score 1):

The approach that solved my problem is to use a list inside  and simply expand it in my profile config. E.g. 
 Root plugin config:

```
<includes>
  <include>com/org/project/**</include>
</includes>
```

Profile plugin config:

```
<includes>
  <include>com/org/project/**</include>
  <include>com/org/staging/**</include>
</includes>
```